# Uniform convergence of integrated Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$  is $2\pi$-periodic and integrable on $[0,2\pi]$ with Fourier coefficients $a_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(y) \cos (ny) \, dy$, ($n = 0,1,\ldots$) and $b_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(y) \sin( ny) \, dy$, ($n=1,2,\ldots)$.

I want to show the function $F(x) = -\frac{a_0x}{2}+ \int_0^x f(t) \, dt $ is $2\pi$-periodic with a Fourier series that converges pointwise and uniformly everywhere and this is true even if Fourier series of $f$ does not converge.

My effort: I showed that $F$ has period $2\pi$ with

$$F(x+2\pi) = -a_0\pi  - \frac{a_0x}{2}+ \int_0^{x+ 2\pi} f(t) \,dt = -a_0\pi + F(x) + \int_{x}^{x + 2\pi}f(t) \, dt \\ = F(x) +\pi ( - a_0 + \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(t) \, dt) = F(x)$$

I know that $F$ is continuous and of bounded variation so its Fourier series converges.  But how do I show that $F$- Fourier series is uniformly convergent?

Comment: Is your integral Riemann or Lebesgue?

Comment: I would assume Riemann integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function
$$
               g(x)= \int_0^x f(t)dt-\frac{x}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)dt
$$
is periodic and continuous on $[0,2\pi]$, and is of bounded variation on $[0,2\pi]$ because $f$ is bounded (assuming $f$ is Riemann integrable, as you indicated in your comments.) Therefore, the Fourier series for $g$ converges uniformly to $g$ on $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Thanks -- but what theorem are you quoting here to get uniform convergence. Any way to prove it directly?

Comment: @SAS : https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Jordan_criterion  The Jordan convergence theorem is one of the older results. The basic Jordan convergence theorem dates back to 1881. It is one of the cleanest and most powerful of the classical Fourier convergence results. It's great for Engineering and Physics because almost every function of interest has to be of bounded variation in Engineering and Physics. And if you add a simple continuity condition, you also end up with uniform convergence.